# Find the number of roots of equation $z^5 -12z^2+14=0$ that lie in the region {$z \in \Bbb C : 2 \leq |z|< \frac {5}{2}$}

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Problem**: Find the number of roots of equation $z^5 -12z^2+14=0$ that lie in the region
>
> {$z \in \Bbb C  :  2 \leq |z|< \frac {5}{2}$}
>
> **Solution** :
>
> In  $f(z)=z^5 -12z^2+14=0$, there is $2$ change in sign
>
> So it has two positive real roots
>
> Now $f(2)f(2.5) <0$
>
> So two positive real roots lie between $2$ and $2.5$
>
> In  $-z^5 -12z^2+14=0$, there is $1$ change in sign
>
> So it has one negative real roots (It will not lie  between $2$ and $2.5$)

I have no idea of other two conjugate complex roots

Please help me in finding the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use Rouché's theorem.

On the outer circle $\lvert z\rvert = \frac{5}{2}$, we have

$$\lvert z\rvert ^5 = \frac{3125}{32} = 97 + \frac{21}{32} > 89 = 75 + 14 = 12\lvert z\rvert^2+14 \geqslant \lvert -12z^2 + 14\rvert,$$

so by Rouché's theorem, $f(z) = z^5 - 12z^2 + 14$ has as many zeros in the disk $\lvert z\rvert < \frac{5}{2}$ as $z^5$ has, counting multiplicity. So all five zeros of $f$ lie in the larger disk.

On the inner circle, we have

$$\lvert z^5+14\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert^5+14 = 32+14 = 46 < 48 = 12\lvert z\rvert^2 = \lvert -12z^2\rvert,$$

so by Rouché's theorem, in the smaller disk $\lvert z\rvert < 2$, $f$ has as many zeros (counting multiplicity) as $-12z^2$ has, namely $2$.

Thus in the annulus $2 <\lvert z\rvert < \frac{5}{2}$, there are three zeros of $f$.

> So two positive real roots lie between $2$ and $2.5$

That is wrong, on the interval $[2,2.5]$ the function is strictly increasing ($5x^4 - 24x > 0$ there), so $f$ has only one real root between $2$ and $2.5$.